# Magnetic Launcher for a Spacecraft

Tags: rail-gun

Is it possible to launch a spacecraft into space with a magnetic accelerator? If so, what materials would it require?

Answer (score -2):

It is completely possible, with the right materials. Carbon nonofibers can be used to make a space elevator, and the magnetic ramp could accelerate the spacecraft to 11km per second, which will make it escape earth gravity

Comment: Do you have any references or calculations to back up your assertions?